# Google map API setIcon is functioning wierdly

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

First marker.setIcon never worked for me. 
I checked in browser console, this is what it shows:

[image]

So I tried using markerObject.icon = "/Content/img/icon_critical.svg"
(Actually it should be "/Content/img/icon_selected.svg", I was trying to check if its the image that it can't access)

And that is giving me a wierd output. No matter which marker i click, only a particular marker icon changes all the time.And everything else just remains the same. Plus this change doesn't occur every time. Its like sometimes its happening, sometimes it just doesn't do anything

The code i used to add the handler is

```
var cautionIcon = "/Content/img/icon_caution.svg";
var criticalIcon = "/Content/img/icon_critical.svg";
var selectIcon = "/Content/img/icon_selected.svg";


var options = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34, 151),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, //aerial //canvasDark //grayscale            
        zoomControl: true
    };

self.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('deviceMap'), options);

var setDeviceLocationData = function setDeviceLocationData(minLatitude, minLongitude, maxLatitude, maxLongitude, deviceLocations) {
    var i;
    var loc;
    var mapOptions;
    var pin;
    var pinOptions;

    if (!self.map) {
        return;
    }

    if (!boundsSet) {
        boundsSet = true;
        self.map.fitBounds(
            new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
                new google.maps.LatLng(maxLatitude, minLongitude),
                new google.maps.LatLng(minLatitude, maxLongitude)
            )
        );            
    }

    if (deviceLocations) {
        for (i = 0; i < deviceLocations.length; ++i) {
            loc = new google.maps.LatLng(deviceLocations[i].latitude, deviceLocations[i].longitude);                

            pinOptions = {
                position: loc,
                map: self.map,
                zIndex: deviceLocations[i].status
            };

            switch (deviceLocations[i].status) {
                case 1:
                    pinOptions.icon = cautionIcon;
                    break;

                case 2:
                    pinOptions.icon = criticalIcon;
                    break;
            }

            pin = new google.maps.Marker(pinOptions);
            google.maps.event.addListener(pin, 'click', function () {
                pin.setIcon(selectIcon); // this never works
                pin.icon = resources.selectedIcon;  // this works sometimes with that wierd output i mentioned above.
            });
        }
    }
}
```

This method setDeviceLocationData gets called every 5 secs in the success callback of an ajax method which in turn calls a web api controller that returns deviceLocations.

deviceLocations looks something like this:

u can use deviceLocations like below:

```
var deviceLocations = [
{
   "latitude": "33.5346",
   "longitude": "88.579989",
   "status":"1"
},
{
   "latitude": "33.53566",
   "longitude": "88.173395",
   "status":"2"
},
{
   "latitude": "33.6346",
   "longitude": "88.570989",
   "status":"1"
},
{
   "latitude": "33.1346",
   "longitude": "88.679889",
   "status":"1"
},];
```

PS: Everything else works except the marker color change.
I tried viewing an infobox but worked just fine.

Could it be because I might have an API key issue? Like I have an old version api key. Or is it that the map wouldn't have loaded at all if it was something like that.

And in my Google Developers Console I have only 1 api key, and that shows something like this. Incase this helps.

[image]

Comment: The `.setIcon` method works for me ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/bf0dh8mo/)) (created a [mcve] from the posted code).  Setting the `.icon` property of the marker directly is dangerous, as that is not documented and may change.

Comment: @geocodezip: That's what I'm saying, its not working for me. I never said that it shouldn't be working for anyone at all. Could it be some api key conflict that I'm having?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your problem.  Unlikely to have anything to do with the API key.  This line `pin.icon = resources.selectedIcon;` should be removed from your code.

Comment: @geocodezip: Ok. And the fiddle: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/SunainaDG/mthhm8au/1/). It's giving the same issue in the ifddle as well. I'm definitely going wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pin.setIcon(selectIcon); // this never works
```

You say "this never works", but it does work, albeit on the last marker.  That is a sign of a common problem in markers created in loops, which can be fixed with function closure or using the `this` inside the click listener (instead of `pin` which is left referencing the last marker).

```
var pin = new google.maps.Marker(pinOptions);
google.maps.event.addListener(pin, 'click', function () {
    this.setIcon(selectIcon); // this never works
});
```

[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/mthhm8au/3/)

[image: screen shot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
var geocoder;
var map;

var deviceLocations = [{
  "latitude": "33.5346",
  "longitude": "88.579989",
  "status": "1"
}, {
  "latitude": "33.53566",
  "longitude": "88.173395",
  "status": "2"
}, {
  "latitude": "33.6346",
  "longitude": "88.570989",
  "status": "1"
}, {
  "latitude": "33.1346",
  "longitude": "88.679889",
  "status": "1"
}];

function initialize() {
  var loc;
  var pinOptions;
  var pin;
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(33, 88),
      zoom: 8,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });


  if (deviceLocations) {
    for (i = 0; i < deviceLocations.length; ++i) {
      loc = new google.maps.LatLng(deviceLocations[i].latitude, deviceLocations[i].longitude);

      pinOptions = {
        position: loc,
        map: map,
        // zIndex: deviceLocations[i].status // InvalidValueError: setZIndex: not a number
      };

      switch (deviceLocations[i].status) {
        case 1:
          pinOptions.icon = cautionIcon;
          break;

        case 2:
          pinOptions.icon = criticalIcon;
          break;
      }

      var pin = new google.maps.Marker(pinOptions);
      google.maps.event.addListener(pin, 'click', function() {
        this.setIcon(selectIcon); // this never works
      });
    }
  }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
var cautionIcon = "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/orange.png";
var criticalIcon = "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/yellow.png";
var selectIcon = "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png";
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```